# C++11 Threads: sleep for a remaining time

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm trying to implement an update thread for my small game with C++11 threads. I've got the update cycle going on "as fast as possible", but I'd like to limit it to say, 60 times per second. How do I get the remaining time left?

```
Core::Core()
{
    std::thread updateThread(update); // Start update thread
}

void Core::update()
{
    // TODO Get start time
    // Here happens the actual update stuff
    // TODO Get end time
    // double duration = ...; // Get the duration

    // Sleep if necessary
    if(duration < 1.0 / 60.0)
    {
        _sleep(1.0 / 60.0 - duration);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't time in milliseconds already? Why the division?

Comment: @erbdex to get the time in milliminutes.

Comment: If you don't detach or join with `updateThread` before its destructor is called, it will terminate your program.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is Pete's correct answer (which I up-voted) but with some code thrown in to show how much easier it is done than the other answers:

```
// desired frame rate
typedef std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<1, 60>> frame_duration;

void Core::update()
{
    // Get start time
    auto start_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    // Get end time
    auto end_time = start_time + frame_duration(1);
    // Here happens the actual update stuff

    // Sleep if necessary
    std::this_thread::sleep_until(end_time);
}
```

Any time you're using `<chrono>`, and you see you're manually converting units, you're opening yourself up to bugs, either immediately, or in future maintenance.  Let `<chrono>` do the conversions for you.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using C++11 threads, you're not limited to whatever that `_sleep` function does. C++11 threads have `sleep_for`, which takes a duration (i.e., sleep for 10 seconds), and `sleep_until`, which takes a time point (i.e., sleep until next Thursday). For a thread that has to wake up at fixed intervals, `sleep_until` is the way to go. Just sleep until the next wakeup time.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the functions and clocks provided in the [chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono) header.

For example:

```
using double_milliseconds = std::chrono::duration<double, std::chrono::milliseconds::period>;

auto t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
/* do work here */
auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<double_milliseconds>(t1 - t0).count();
```

Comment: Converting to `double elapsed_milliseconds` manually is undesirable. Instead one should stick with strongly typed `chrono::duration`s. See Howard Hinnant's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20381816/365496).

Comment: @bames53 Is it better like this? :)

Comment: If there's a good reason to use a generic type like double to represent a duration (e.g., some third party API requires it) then this is a fine example. Absent such a requirement `.count()` should be avoided, however. `chrono::duration` provides strong typing for quantities of time and should be taken advantage of whenever possible. So the way I would get elapse time is `auto elapsed = t1 - t0;`

Comment: @melak47:  Additionally `duration_cast`, though correct, is unnecessarily verbose.  When converting to floating point units, you can depend upon implicit conversions: `double_milliseconds elapsed = t1 - t0;`

Comment: @melak47:  A more concise spelling of `std::chrono::milliseconds::period` is `std::milli`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to limit the framerate is to keep track of how long it takes your entire update function. After that you need to sleep the remaining time:

In this example i used [timeGetTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to measure time but you can use any other function that has high precision

```
void Core::Update()
{
    unsigned int start_time = timeGetTime();
    ActualUpdate();
    unsigned int end_time = timeGetTime();
    unsigned int frame_time = end_time - start_time;

    const unsigned int miliseconds_per_frame = 1000 / 60;
    if(frame_time < miliseconds_per_frame)
    {
        Sleep(miliseconds_per_frame - frame_time);
    }
}
```